# How do I access two arrays from a form simultaneously in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I receive two arrays from a form. In the .php file, I need to insert the values of each array into a column of the table.
- use the foreach loop to access the elements of one array and complete the insertion for only one column. When I do the same thing for the next array, I find that the corresponding first column elements are null in each row while for the first array, the corresponding second column elements are null. Is there anyway to avoid this and insert the array elements one after the other?
- I understand that foreach cannot be applied to two arrays so is there any other way I can access both the arrays simultaneously for insertion into a table?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop:

```
 foreach($_POST['someField_1'] as $key => $value)
 {
     $fieldOne = $value;
     $fieldTwo = $_POST['someField_2'][$key];
 }
```

Obviously change the _POST variables to whatever you've named the fields.
As long as your field names are named something like: `name="someField_1[]"` and `name="someField_2[]"` You can use the foreach loop in this way.

**EDIT**

Take this HTML for your input form:

```
Forename: <input type="text" name="forename[]"> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname[]">
Forename: <input type="text" name="forename[]"> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname[]">
Forename: <input type="text" name="forename[]"> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname[]">
```

So that form allows you to enter forenames and surnames for up to 3 people. Each field has the exact same name: `forename[]` and `surname[]`

To retrieve each of the values, you would use this PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['forename'] as $key => $forename)
{
    echo 'Forename: ' . $forename;
    echo ' ';
    echo 'Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'][$key] . '<br />';
}
```

This works because when you submit a field like `forename[]`, with square brackets at the end, PHP will automatically convert this to an array. `$key` is a number which starts at 0, and goes on for however many fields there are.

PHP uses the `$key` to retrieve the correct fields. You could also write your HTML like this:

```
Forename: <input type="text" name="forename[0]"> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname[0]">
Forename: <input type="text" name="forename[1]"> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname[1]">
Forename: <input type="text" name="forename[2]"> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname[2]">
```

You see I've put a number between the square brackets? PHP will detect this and loop through the arrays.

You could even use a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['forename']); $i++)
{
    echo 'Forename: ' . $_POST['forename'][$i];
    echo 'Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'][$i];
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the "as $key => $value" means? I looked it up and didn't really understand it?

Comment: well $key is the key and $value is the value, all array elements are a pair, one key one value

Comment: Is $key the array index and $value the actual array element?